# Entity Framework 6 Connectionstring confusion

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, connection-string

I have an interesting problem.

In my context, if I call the connection string itself in base method, there is no problem. It works fine. But If I try to get the connection string from any config file, Ef's mind is confused.
Here my connection string:
[image]
Here is my context :
[image]
and when I try to call it, here is the result:[image]
Entity framework changing the initial catalog's name to name of connection string. I overcome the situation by making them same. But unfortunetly in the production server something is going wrong and it isn't even initiliazing the database. When I place the connection string itself, it works very well.
this's the exception on production server:

```
Connection ID "18014398515387564057", Request ID "8000001c-0001-fa00-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)
       ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): The system cannot find the file specified.
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
         at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
         at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
         at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
         at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
         at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
         at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
         at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
         at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
         at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
         at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<>c.<Open>b__13_0(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)
         at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
         at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
         at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.<>c__DisplayClass60_0.<UsingConnection>b__0()
         at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Execute>b__0()
         at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
         at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
         at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
         at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection sqlConnection, Action`1 act)
         at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.CreateDatabaseFromScript(Nullable`1 commandTimeout, DbConnection sqlConnection, String createDatabaseScript)
         at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
         at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
         at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase()
         at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection)
         at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
         at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
         at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
         at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update()
         at System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
         at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClass66_0`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__0()
         at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
         at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
         at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<>c.<InitializeDatabase>b__58_0(InternalContext c)
         at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
         at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
         at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
         at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
         at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
         at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
         at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
         at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
         at System.Linq.Queryable.Join[TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult](IQueryable`1 outer, IEnumerable`1 inner, Expression`1 outerKeySelector, Expression`1 innerKeySelector, Expression`1 resultSelector)
         at Mbis.Dispatcher.DataAccess.Concrete.EntityFramework.EfEnvelopeDal.GetEnvelopesWithFirstDocument(Expression`1 filter) in D:\MyProjects\MbisDispatcher\Mbis.Dispatcher\Mbis.Dispatcher.DataAccess\Concrete\EntityFramework\EfEnvelopeDal.cs:line 20
         at Mbis.Dispatcher.Business.Concrete.EnvelopeManager.GetEnvelopeDetailList() in D:\MyProjects\MbisDispatcher\Mbis.Dispatcher\Mbis.Dispatcher.Business\Concrete\EnvelopeManager.cs:line 123
         at Mbis.Dispatcher.WebApi.Controllers.EnvelopeController.GetList() in D:\MyProjects\MbisDispatcher\Mbis.Dispatcher\Mbis.Dispatcher.WebApi\Controllers\EnvelopeController.cs:line 20
         at lambda_method2(Closure , Object , Object[] )
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I try to use your code to set the connection string via the `nameOrConnectionString` property, but it will show the following prompt:

[image]

After modifying the code as below, everything works well, you can try it.

Add a string parameter in the DbContext constructor:

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public SchoolContext(string connString) : base(connString)
    {
    }
```

In the Startup.ConfigureServices method, register the DBContext with connection string.

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddScoped<SchoolContext>(_ => 
            new SchoolContext(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    }
```

the Connection string in the appsetting.json file as below:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=EF6MVCCore;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
```

When debug the code, the dbcontext connection string like this:

[image]

More detail information, you can refer [ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6?view=aspnetcore-5.0)